# How to convert dbm to watts on Matlab

Tags: matlab, math

Good day

I want to convert PT=47dbm to watts,how can i do that conversion on matlab?

On my code I have it as PT=50,12watts, but i want to do the proper conversion from dbm to watts using Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The watt to dBm conversion follows the following rule:

```
dBW = 10 * log10(P[w])

dBm = 10 * log10(1000 * P[w])
    = 10 * log10(P[w]) + 10 * log10(1000)
    = 10 * log10(P[w]) + 10 * 3
    = 10 * log10(P[w]) + 30
    = dBW + 30
```

Hence, the inverse path will be:

```
P[w] = 10 ^ ((P[dBm] - 30) / 10);
```

Thus, in Matlab:

```
P_w = 47;
P_dBm = 10 ^ ((P_w - 30) / 10); % 50.12
```